# Share page Display Blank Screen

Tags: sharing

We are using LinkedIn from past few months and every thing works fine since their last API upgrade on 12th March.

Our mobile apps open linkedIn in browser every thing works fine the clients gets Authenticated and login Successfully , once they login the contacts list shows blank and error returned unauthorized 
could any one know whats the reason/solution of it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have Checked the new API updates that LinkedIn activated as if yesterday? 
If you are pulling anything apart from Basic profile .. Location or not using the new w_share permission it will most likely be responded as a Bad request. Check the developer.LinkedIn.com for more reference

Comment: No we are not pulling anything from user profile , just authenticating the user and then redirecting him to Share screen yes i already enabled w_share in my developer console